# android create widget menu icon

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, icons, android-launcher

when browsing the widget menu on Android 3.0+ some widgets have simple icons and others have more of a screenshot of what the widget actually looks like.

How would I portray the latter in my own widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the widget preview app on your Android emulator to take a screenshot of your widget and send it to yourself via email:
[image]

Then inside your appwidget-provider XML you can specify this:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    [...]
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
    />
```